# Hematophagic Organism Body Size

Tags: biology, evolution

So how large of an organism can a diet of strictly of blood support? In a modern Earth setting it might be a bit hard for a large hematophagic organism to find a suitable group of prey that it won't drain completely, so what if it had access to megafauna the size of dinosaurs?

Comment: Please proof read your question. It is unclear if you are asking about the size of the eater or of the eaten.

Answer (score 2):

given the right conditions, something like an allosaurus-vampire could shepherd dinosaurs or other megafauna and feed off them repetitively without killing them. A large straight-up predator would need to either kill and consume its prey or else feed repetitively and leave them alive. Perhaps it lives like a sheep dog, protecting its megafauna from other predators and mega-vampires. The prey-animals might not even resist feeding.